# How to get parents by IDs when using polymorphic associations

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

I have a many-to-many relation table `site_sections` with the following columns:

```
id
site_id
section_id
```

which is used a join table between `sections` and `sites` tables. So one site has many **sections** and a section is available in many **sites**.
`Sites` table has the following columns:

```
id
store_number
```

The `sites_sections` table is used in a polymorphic association with `parameters` table.

I'd like to find all the parameters corresponding to the **site sections** for a specific **site** by its `store_number`. Is it possible to pass in an array of site_settings.id to SQL using the `IN` clause, something like that:

```
Parameter.where("parent_id IN (" + [1, 2, 3, 4] + ") and parent_type ='com.models.SiteSection'");
```

where `[1, 2, 3, 4]` should be an array of IDs from **sites_sections** table or there is a better solution ?

Comment: I Think I found the solution:

Comment: 1. Find the Site by store_number: ` Site aSite = Site.findFirst("store_number=?", STORE_NUMBER);
2. Find `SitesSettings` list for the found site and include the `Parameters`: `List<SiteSection> siteSections= SiteSection.where("site_id=?", aSite.get("id")).include(Parameter.class);`
3. Then loop on `site_settings` and get the corresponding `parameters`: `for (SiteSection siteSection : siteSections) { List<Parameter> siteParams = siteSection.getAll(Parameter.class);`
4. Loop on Parameters: `for (Parameter siteParam : siteParams) {` and find the needed values.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct:

```
Site aSite = Site.findFirst("store_number=?", STORE_NUMBER); 
List<SiteSection> siteSections= SiteSection.where("site_id=?", aSite.getId()).include(Parameter.class); 
for (SiteSection siteSection : siteSections) { 
  List<Parameter> siteParams = siteSection.getAll(Parameter.class);
  for (Parameter siteParam : siteParams) { ... }
}
```

In addition, by using the `include()`, you are also avoiding an N+1 problem: http://javalite.io/lazy_and_eager#improve-efficiency-with-eager-loading

However there can be a catch. If you have a very large number of parameters, you will be using a lot of memory, since `include()` loads all results into heap at once. If your result sets are relatively small, you are saving resources by running a single query. If your result sets are large, you are wasting heap space.

See docs: [LazyList#include()](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/org/javalite/activejdbc/LazyList.html#include-java.lang.Class...-)

Side note: use `aSite.getId()` or `aSite.getLongId()` instead of `aSite.get("id")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Igor, - a cool feature  `getId`; `getLongId`, didn't know that :). Is it possible to convert to JSON an error when a record not found ?

Comment: Actually I return from the controller `respond(notFound(param("storeNumber")));`
where `notFound` method just returns `return "No site found for the provided store number: " + storeNumber;`

Comment: sure, do not forget to set the status code: `respond(message).status(404);`, and do not forget to test that you even have a parameter: `if(!blank("storeNumber"))` ...

Comment: But when I add `status(404)` to the response: `respond(notFound(param("storeNumber"))).status(404);`I get the template not found error: `Failed to render template: '/system/error.ftl', with layout: '/layouts/default_layout'; Template "/system/error.ftl" not found.`. Should I really have it in case of JSON response only ?

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to send an error message as JSON instead of this way: `JsonHelper.toJsonString(new String("No site found for the specified store number"));` ? Should I use a Error class as a wrapper to be able to populate its attributes and convert it to JSON the same way ?

Comment: I've found this way with `map` method: `return JsonHelper.toJsonString(map("error", "No site found for the specified store number: " + storeNumber));`

Comment: you should not delete `/system/error.ftl`. Framework needs it to display errors. Also, look in the log file to see what error it  is trying to render

Comment: Igor, there are no views in the current application, it will be an API. I have defined abstract APIController that returns JSON and has no layout: `public abstract class APIController extends AppController {@Override
    protected String getContentType() {
        return "application/json";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getLayout() {
        return null;
    }`

Comment: you still need that file so that the framework could  display internal errors not caught in your code. You can edit that file to display JSON. In fact, I use Freemarker all  the time to build JSON web services. Here is a pefrect example of a collection displayed in JSON using ActiveWeb https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-rest/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/people

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look. Nevertheless, it seems a little bit unusual to have views to display JSON. I'll take a try.

Comment: trust me, views will provide a LOT of flexibility you do not have now